# How to scramble text with items in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try to type `§llll` in the anvil it won't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the title of the question, it seems that you want to add the "magic" effect on an item name by renaming it via an Anvil.

However, **it is impossible to input the `§` symbol in an Anvil**. In-game, the symbol can only be used in Book & Quills, as well as the chat box. Therefore, you cannot legitimately format item names with an Anvil in Vanilla.

Moreover, note that `l` is used to bold text while `k` is used to scramble. `&llll` or `§llll` will produce **lll** only. For future reference, you can visit the Minecraft wiki page for [Formatting codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes).

Comment: You can also use `§r` to revert the text back to normal

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible to put the `§` symbol. If you go to the keyboard languages and scroll down to the “symbols” one, you are able to type that special character. This will only work on devices with a mobile keypad, or a keypad with special symbols, and will not work with copy and paste.

Comment: Can you provide evidence or further explanation? This question is talking about the Java Edition of Minecraft, where it is impossible to get the section sign.

Comment: The issue is not typing the character, that's just `Alt` + `0167`. If it is possible, could you explain?

Comment: The Minecraft Wiki currently states that items can be renamed with colours and effects only in Bedrock Editon, the anvil input field does not accept the `§` symbol.